# angular js combine asynchronous and synchronous code

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, angularjs-service, angular-promise

I am using angular `resource` modul to work with my restfull webserver. For exampe i have a method which returns an array of 10 elements and what i want to do is just save result into some javascript variable (**not in angular scope**) called `books`.

So i have written a simple method which looks like this:

```
function getBooks(user_id) {
    var books = [];
    BookFactory.getBooks.query({ id: user_id }).$promise.then(function (result) {
        angular.forEach(result, function(i) {
            books.push(i);
        });
    });
    return books;
}
```

Let's assume that **BookFactory.getBooks.query** works as expected and truly returns 10 elements. 
So there is a simple logic inside this function, i just push each element to the array **books**.

Also i have a test function for testing `getBooks()` function. Here it is:

```
$scope.testGetBooksMethod = function (user_id) {
    var resut = getBooks(user_id);
    alert(resut.length);
};
```

The result in alert will be always 0. I know that this part of code:

```
BookFactory.getBooks.query({ id: user_id }).$promise.then(function (result) {
            angular.forEach(result, function(i) {
                books.push(i);
            });
        });
```

works asynchronously and until server request is processing, function `getBooks()` returns an empty array of books (please correct me if i am wrong).

Here is a question, how can i edit my function, to work it correctly. I want to get data from rest, fill the array `books` with this data and then return it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So you know what asynchronous code is and still *"I want to get data from rest, fill the array books with this data and then return it"*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use promise concept here, `testGetBooksMethod` of controller function will wait till `getBooks` of service method will complete its call. For that you need to return the `BookFactory.getBooks.query` promise from `getBooks` function. After data gets retrieve the books are will get created & will return from the `getBooks` method. While calling `getBooks` method you need to use `.then` function that will continue the chain promise thing, when data is returned from the `getBooks` this then function will get the data returned from the your service.

```
function getBooks(user_id) {
    var books = [];
    return BookFactory.getBooks.query({ id: user_id }).$promise.then(function (result) {
        angular.forEach(result, function(i) {
            books.push(i);
        });
        return books;
    });
}
```

**Controller**

```
$scope.testGetBooksMethod = function (user_id) {
    getBooks(user_id).then(function(resut){
        alert(resut.length);
    });
};
```

Comment: @user3127896 oh..Thanks..but why not mine answer..? Just curious to know that.. so that I can improve on this..

Comment: i saw your answer second=)

Comment: @user3127896 you could check the time actual timestamp by hovering on answered 13 minutes ago .. Its here **dsfq** `2015-07-05 08:46:12Z` and **pankajparkar** `2015-07-05 08:45:59Z` ..Now decide who answered first.

Comment: @user3127896 basically I beated him by 13 secs.. I don't want to force you to accept answer..but just showing you the difference in time..As you said you saw my answer later

Answer (score 2):

> I want to get data from rest, fill the array books with this data and then return it.

This is the thing. Asynchronous programming is not really compatible with synchronous. So you can't just combine them. However you could work in a *synchronous-like* way, and this is where promises comes very powerful. You don't return `data`, you return stateful [Promise object](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) instead.

So instead of returning `books` return a Promise *for this books*:

```
function getBooks(user_id) {
    return BookFactory.getBooks.query({ id: user_id }).$promise;
}
```

Then in consuming code you would use this wrapper object with underlying state control mechanism which will proceed when books are loaded and available:

```
$scope.testGetBooksMethod = function (user_id) {
    getBooks(user_id).then(function(books) {
        alert(books.length);
    });
};
```